# Mongodb aggregate: get referenced document field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I would like to get a field value from a referenced document. Mongodb-version is 3.4.

Lets say I have 2 collections foo and bar. Foo has a reference to bar:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c713ea502dea387860eba"),
  "stack" : "overflow",
  "bar" : {
    "$ref" : "bar",
    "$id" : ObjectId("5b6c70e1a502dea387860ea6"),
    "$db" : "stackoverflow"
  }
}
```

And the corresponding bar document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c70e1a502dea387860ea6"),
  "name" : "bar-2"
}
```

I tried the following aggregate function to archieve this result:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c713ea502dea387860eba"),
  "stack" : "overflow",
  "barName" : "bar-2"
}
```

Aggregrate-function:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5b6c713ea502dea387860eba") }},
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'bar',
        localField: 'bar',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: "bar"
      }
  },
  {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        stack: "$stack",
        barName: "$bar.name"
    }
  }

  ]).pretty()
```

But my result is this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c713ea502dea387860eba"),
  "stack" : "overflow",
  "barName" : []
}
```

I tried to google it, I looked into the mongodb docs but was not able to find a solution for this.

Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't find a solution for my problem I found this [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466). It seems like this is currently not possible with mongodb DBRef() fields.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `bar` and also your `localField` is `bar.id` not only `bar`

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5b6c713ea502dea387860eba") }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "bar",
    "localField": "bar.id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "bar"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$bar" },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "stack": "$stack",
    "barName": "$bar.name"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, as far I remember. With this query im gettin' `Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms`. Is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: Are you using mongoose? Because probably your db name is incorrect here

Comment: No I'm currently in `robo 3t`-shell on the local installed mongodb. But the document did create symfony (doctrine mongodb-odm), if thats what you wanted to know

Comment: I'm also seeing, if I'm only do the `$lookup` without `$project` and `$unwind` than `bar` is an empty array. Is this the expected behaviour? Or does that give me a hint that something does not work properly with the `$lookup` (like you said, maybe with a incorrect db-name or equal)

Comment: your `bar` should contain the array of object `[{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c70e1a502dea387860ea6"),
  "name" : "bar-2"
}]`... I think your db name is incorrect

Comment: ok I guess it is this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466. So i dont think there is a solution for my problem. Thank you anyway

Comment: Presumably unwind is for arrays, isn't it? What can be done when you have a single reference? No array whatsoever

Comment: @JavierGuzmán Please ask a new question describing your exact problem

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, I am using Mongodb compass.

Comment: @MichelaDennis kindly post a new question stating "what is not working"

Comment: @Ashh my scenario would not warrant a new question. My question is the same as this. The solution provided didn't give me any result for lookup for a dbref.

Comment: This solution works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790733/how-project-dbref-on-spring-mongodb-aggregation
If this is relevant: My Mongo version is 4.0.3